# Using Lean to prove the convergence of a sequence is equivalent to the equality of its limit supremum = limit infimum = limit of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm a newbie trying to use the Lean proof assistant to prove this lemma: The convergence of a sequence, i.e. a(n) tends to α,  is equivalent to having its limit supremum = limit infimum = α. I'll use:

- sup/inf as shorthand for supremum/infimum
- limsup/liminf as shorthand for limit supremum/limit infimum

**TLDR** : How do I fix the code below to take the minimum of my set of upper bounds? Lean gives the error "failed to synthesize type class instance".

I'm using a basic proof hinging on the below logic (apologies as I can't upload pictures yet... first time user here):

- => direction: a - ε ≤ inf a(m) ≤ sup a(m) ≤ a + ε for all m ≥ n. Then take the limsup and liminf along with ε being arbitrary to conclude equality.
- <= direction: inf a(m) ≥ a - ε, and sup a(m) ≤ a + ε for all m ≥ n. Then for all m ≥ n, |a(m) - a| < ε.

To do this in Lean, I first define convergent sequences and then work on defining limsup/liminf. I'm taking these sequences as being elements of a set of sequences satisfying convergence/boundedness because I don't know of any other way to define them, and mathlib (the library that Lean uses) seems not to have these pre-defined.

To define the limsup/liminf, I must first define a supremum as the least upper bound of a bounded sequence. The current issue is that I cannot take the minimum of this set of upper bounds as Lean gives an error saying: "failed to synthesize type class instance".

1. **My question is how do I overcome this error?** The min function requires the object it acts on to be linearly ordered - Can I use the definition of linear_order in mathlib to fix this, and if so how do I use it?

My plan is to then define limsup/liminf as such: consider the bounded sequence f(n), where n is a natural number. The sup of f(m) for all m > n can then be found by using up_bounds with m = n + N for an arbitrary natural number N. I'll then try to take limsup as being when N tends to infinity - I'd greatly appreciate any tips you guys might have!

### Code is here:

```
import data.real.basic

import tactic
 
def set_convergent_seq : set (ℕ → ℝ) := {a | ∀ (ε : ℝ), ε > 0 → ∃ (N : ℕ), ∀ (n : ℕ), n ≥ N → ∃ (l : ℝ), abs (a n - l) ≤ ε}

def set_bounded_seq : set (ℕ → ℝ) := {b | ∃ (B : ℝ), ∀ (n : ℕ), abs (b n) ≤ B}

def up_bounds (b ∈ set_bounded_seq) : set ℝ := {U | ∀ (n: ℕ), abs (b n) ≤ U}

def supremum (b ∈ set_bounded_seq) := min(up_bounds (b)) **error comes here**
```

Comment: By your definition of `set_convergent_seq` it contains all sequences, choosing `l = a n`.

Comment: I don't have it installed but I'm pretty sure mathlib has this stuff if you know where to look. Probably done with filters or something. Before you go into that, I think you'd find [this tutorial](https://github.com/leanprover-community/tutorials) useful to work through.